# Object showing behind an obstruction

Tags: mesh, objects, 3d-view, blenderkit

I downloaded a pair of soccer kit mesh via Blender kit, and whatever position my view is in the viewport, the kits would be visible even if there is an obvious obstruction in front of it.

This is the front view
[image]

This is the bottom view
[image]

Considering that the shoes are above the rock, I shouldn't be able to see them in bottom view.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untick *In Front* checkbox in the *Object Properties* tab.

[image]